# Unable To Connect To Internet Sites Via Live USB - Wi-Fi Settings Are Correct

Tags: internet, live-usb, dns, firewall, connection

I was running my Ubuntu Live via USB for the first time. All of my Wi-Fi settings were correct and I was able to get a DHCP address on my network but I was unable to get to any Internet URL including my local router. It seems as though DNS was not functioning or I was being blocked by my Internet provider. DNS was set to Automatic and both DNS servers were registered. My cell phones Wi-Fi could not connect either. After I rebooted into Windows 10 I was able to connect to Internet URLs again via my computer and on phone.

Has anyone found this to be an issue? I will test tomorrow on my network and on another private network that I use to see if there was a brief network outage. There was no indication in my Wi-Fi router's firewall log of a blockage. It is late and way past my bedtime.

Comment: Sounds like a router and or ISP issue. You say phone and computer both had the issue so not a Ubuntu problem.

Comment: which version of ubuntu were you using on the Live USB? [edit] your question accordingly